# -bash: certutil: command not found

Tags: linux, certificate

I have a Debian GNU buld on a Raspberry PI. I am trying to install cerficates for a website. Most forums talk about needing CertUtil. But that command is not recognised. A Google reveals no similar issues.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not general computer support issues. Anyway, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxCertManagement for how to download and install the tools.

Comment: try with apt-get install libnss3-tools

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
apt-get update       
apt-get install libnss3-tools
```

This should install the required libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) in Linux

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example.com.key -out example.com.csr
```

Answer correctly, the questions you will be asked from the above command execution.

To view the generated .csr certificate for Linux user

```
openssl req -text -noout -verify -in example.com.csr
```

To view the generated .csr For windows user

```
certutil  example.com.csr
```

Comment: Your diligence is admirable, but this question did receive an accepted answer on the same day as the question, a good 5 years prior... (not to mention this answer can barely qualify as relating to the OPs question).